# Search solution(algorithm or exist library or same)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, schedule

I want to implement some mechanism to scheduling jobs(tasks). But this will have task-pool and can save and reload tasks from database, dynamic tasks changing(from business logic), adding and removing. Furthermore this will work with Spring MVC. Can someone recommend anything like my needs ?

Comment: quartz is one of the best scheduler implementation

Answer (score 2):

Quartz-scheduler is exactly what you're need. It fulfills all your requirements.

The reference for quartz-scheduler itself: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation

And the reference to Spring Framework documentation about integrating with quartz-scheduler: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz

Comment: Yeah, but it is half true. If I will use quartz only then I shall invent library(which will use quartz) like I search... Quartz by itself not realize these features.